# datatables avançadas CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html5, codeigniter

Estou quebrando cabeça com uma coisinha no CodeIgniter, preciso criar uma tabela avançada que expanda detalhes sobre cada item da tabela, como podem ver no código abaixo eu não consigo separar uma linha de detalhe para item da tabela,
att;

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <? //
    $tmpl = array(
        'table_open' => '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabela_poas">',
        'heading_row_start' => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end' => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start' => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end' => '</th>',

        'row_start' => '<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">',
        'row_end' => '</tr>',
        'cell_start' => '<td align="center" role="row">',
        'cell_end' => '</td>',

        'row_alt_start' => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end' => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start' => '<td align="center">',
        'cell_alt_end' => '</td>',

        'table_close' => '</table>'
    );

    //        ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //                TableAdvanced.init('tabela_poas');
            //                iniciar_tabela('tabela_poas');
            Init_mascaras_jquery();
            TableAdvanced.init('tabela_poas');
        });

        //            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //                Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
        //                Layout.init(); // init current layout
        //                Demo.init(); // init demo features
        //
        //            });

    </script>
    <input type="hidden" id="idquadro" value="<? // echo @$quadro_por_id[0]->IDQUADRO; ?>">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <? //

            $detalhes = '

                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Access Key</th>
                                <th>Secret Key</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th> Created</th>
                                <th> Expires</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                           <td class="details" colspan="5">
                           </td>

                           </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>

           ';

            if (isset($dados_produtos[0])) {
                foreach ($dados_produtos as $row) {
                    $cell = array('data' => $detalhes, 'class' => 'highlight', 'colspan' => 7);
                    $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
                    $this->table->set_heading('IdItem', 'Modalidade', 'Área', 'Titulo', 'Beneficiário', 'Valor Aprovado', 'Detalhes');
                    $this->table->add_row(

                        @$row->idpoaitem,
                        @$row->modalidade,
                        @$row->area,
                        @$row->titulo,
                        @$row->beneficiario,
                        @$row->valoraprovado,
                        '  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                    </button>'
                    );

                    $this->table->add_row($cell);
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <? echo $this->table->generate() . '<br><br>'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Já adianto que você **não vai conseguir** fazer algo assim usando a classe nativa do `CodeIgniter` porque ela não permite alteração de atributos das linhas da tabela gerada (o que é lamentável, porque permite que se altere as `cells`).  A solução é estender ou substituir. Estender é melhor, porque você não mexe na base do `framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiquei curioso, e fui pesquisar um pouco sobre sua dúvida. Achei que seu problema seria resolvido com isso [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11/). Veja a aplicação (**você clica na linha para expandir os detalhes**):

```css
.hiddenRow {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Tabela Accordion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#ID</th>
          <th>Access Key</th>
          <th>Secret Key</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Expires</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class='accordion-toggle' data-target='#line_0_details' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">#Access Key0</td>
          <td align="center">#Secret Key0</td>
          <td align="center">#Status0</td>
          <td align="center">#Created0</td>
          <td align="center">#Expires0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
            <div id="line_0_details" class="accordian-body collapse">Detalhes da line 0</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='accordion-toggle' data-target='#line_1_details' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">#Access Key1</td>
          <td align="center">#Secret Key1</td>
          <td align="center">#Status1</td>
          <td align="center">#Created1</td>
          <td align="center">#Expires1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
            <div id="line_1_details" class="accordian-body collapse">Detalhes da line 1</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='accordion-toggle' data-target='#line_2_details' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <td align="center">2</td>
          <td align="center">#Access Key2</td>
          <td align="center">#Secret Key2</td>
          <td align="center">#Status2</td>
          <td align="center">#Created2</td>
          <td align="center">#Expires2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
            <div id="line_2_details" class="accordian-body collapse">Detalhes da line 2</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Só que, pra fazer isso com `CodeIgniter` você tem que estender a classe. O problema é que o framework (em regra) não permite passagem de parâmetros para a composição da tabela. Assim, por exemplo, não seria possível determinar atributos para as linhas dela.

Como você já está usando `Bootstrap`, e já deve ter o `CodeIgniter` devidamente instalado, vamos estender a classe `CI_Table` pra poder modificar os atributos das `<tr>` e `<td>`:

1. **acesse https://github.com/dalehurley/codeigniter-table-rows/archive/master.zip e descompacte `MY_Table.php` para `application/libraries` da sua aplicação;**
2. **Crie um método no seu `controller` com esse código:**

   ```
    function tabela(){
       // Carregando a biblioteca e setando os parâmetros genéricos
       $this->load->library('table');
       $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;"); //->Células vazias
       $this->table->set_heading(array('#ID','Access Key','Secret Key','Status','Created','Expires'));//->Cabeçalho
       // Dados principais
       $data = array(
           array('0','#Access Key0','#Secret Key0','#Status0','#Created0','#Expires0'),
           array('1','#Access Key1','#Secret Key1','#Status1','#Created1','#Expires1'),
           array('2','#Access Key2','#Secret Key2','#Status2','#Created2','#Expires2'),
       );
       // Loop de criação da tabela
       foreach ($data as $i => $row){
           // Insere cada item dos dados principais em uma linha
           $rows[] = [
               'data' => $row,
               'data-toggle' => 'collapse',
               'data-target' => "#line_{$i}_details",
               'class' => 'accordion-toggle'
           ];
           // Cria uma linha oculta com os detalhes de cada linha principal
           $rowData = ['<div id="line_'.$i.'_details" class="accordian-body collapse">Detalhes da line '.$i.'</div>'];
           $rows[]=['data' => $rowData];//->Acrescentando os dados ao ARRAY
           // Este é o estilo da tabela. Só altere o que precisar alterar
           $tmpl = [
               'table_open' => '<table class="table table-bordered">',
               'cell_start' => '<td align="center">',
               'cell_alt_start' => '<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">'
           ];
       }
       // Aplicando o estilo definido
       $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
       // Capturando a string gerada
       $data['tabela'] = $this->table->generate($rows);
       // Carregando dados na VIEW
       $this->load->view('tabela', $data);
   }
   ```
3. **A sua `VIEW` vai ter o seguinte:**

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <title>Tabela Accordion</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <style>
           .hiddenRow {
               padding: 0 !important;
           }
       </style>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div class='container'>
           <br>
           <?= $tabela ?>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```